# error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I got an error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row when i run this sql.

```
CREATE VIEW test 
AS 
  SELECT cc_name, 
         COUNT() AS total, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM bed 
           WHERE respatient_id > 0 
        GROUP BY cc_name) AS occupied_beds, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM bed 
           WHERE respatient_id IS NULL 
        GROUP BY cc_name) AS free_beds 
    FROM bed 
GROUP BY cc_name;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql::Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637613/mysqlerror-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row), [MySQL: Subquery Returns more than one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778239/mysql-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row), [Why does MySQL give "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863665/why-does-mysql-give-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-error), and [help with subquery! returns more than 1 row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419094/help-with-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row).

Comment: @Ken White: Using the same tag/error message does not mean these are duplicates.

Comment: The second one is, including the problem being related to a `COUNT`. Three of the four explain what the error means, which should have led the poster to figuring it out themself. (As would reading the actual error message, looking at the query and thinking "Hmmm. Two possibilities, since there are two subqueries. Maybe I should run them separately to see if they DO return more than one row, and then I can try and figure that part out or ask about it specifically."

Comment: @Ken White: The tag info itself explains the behavior ;)  That's the point of the questions, so there's numerous examples/samples...

Comment: :) Got that. The point is that the asker apparently made absolutely no effort to work it out themselves; a simple search would have turned up the other 4 questions, which should have led them in the direction to look. SO is a great resource, but it shouldn't be the *first* resort for every problem. You should at least try to solve it yourself first, and then look to see if others have, and *then* ask a new question here. I see no mention of "I tried" or "I searched, but the other answers didn't help because". I see instead "I got an error message. Tell me how to fix it. Here's my code." :)

Comment: @Ken White: I agree about effort.  I cut slack for low rep accounts - over a couple hundred & it's pretty obvious they're just leeches :/

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your subselects are returning more than one value - IE:

```
SELECT ...
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM bed 
         WHERE respatient_id IS NULL 
      GROUP BY cc_name) AS free_beds,
       ...
```

...will return a row for each `cc_name`, but SQL doesn't support compacting the resultset for the subselect - hence the error.

Don't need the subselects, this can be done using a single pass over the table using:

```
  SELECT b.cc_name, 
         COUNT(*) AS total, 
         SUM(CASE 
               WHEN b.respatient_id > 0 THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END) AS occupied_beds, 
         SUM(CASE 
               WHEN b.respatient_id IS NULL THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END) AS free_beds 
    FROM bed b
GROUP BY b.cc_name
```

Comment: I think your `SUM`s are a bit hackish; it's more clear to use `COUNT`s, as a1ex07 suggests.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty sure you made a mistake in your test. `COUNT` counts all non-`NULL` values; in your addendum, you have an `ELSE 0`, which would be wrong. (It needs to be `ELSE NULL`, or just omitted.) In your comment, you omit the `ELSE 0`, but I'm betting that that's not what you actually tested.

Comment: @ruakh: Thank you for catching that, updated.  However, I don't see how `SUM` is hackish when it explicitly demonstrates how the calculation is made.  Clearly, `COUNT` requires the user to be aware of the `NULL` handling & construct the query appropriately -- that makes `COUNT` more "hackish" than using `SUM`.

Comment: Well, I guess "hackishness" is subjective, but when the goal is to *count* records with a certain property, I think it's a bit hackish/obfuscated to use a `SUM` over 1 and 0 rather than a `COUNT` over null and non-null values. After all, the whole point of `COUNT` is to count non-null values. But your way obviously works, and if you prefer it, then I can't give you a compellingly objective reason to adopt my preference instead of your own. :-P   I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. Fortunately, this is a very minor thing to disagree over. :-)

Comment: @ruakh: You think it's hackish to explicitly state how the operation is occurring?  The approach is generally regarded as "pattern" rather than anti-pattern.  To each their own, but I think you'll find yourself alone with your belief.  If there was a performance benefit, then I'd support it but if there's not then I write for maintenance & readability to the layman.

Comment: I think consistently using `COUNT` for counts is much more readable than sometimes using `COUNT` and sometimes using `SUM`, as you seem to advocate. (I notice that -- quite sensibly -- you wrote `COUNT(*)` rather than `SUM(1)`.)

Comment: @ruakh: Readability is larger than seeing "count" vs SUM - IE knowing that omitting the ELSE in a CASE returns NULL, or how COUNT handles NULL/non-NULL.

Comment: Well, "how COUNT handles NULL/non-NULL" is the very definition of COUNT: it counts non-NULLs, that's what it's for. As for omitting the `ELSE NULL`, I think you're right, but I don't feel strongly about it. By the way, I'm obviously *not* alone in my belief, since that's how a1ex07 chose to write it, and a Google search for "count case when" finds many, many examples. (But a search for "sum case when" plus "then 1 else 0 end" also finds many examples, so you're not alone, either!)

Answer (score 4):

This is because your subqueries (the `SELECT` bits that are inside parentheses) are returning multiple rows for each outer row. The problem is with the `GROUP BY`; if you want to use subqueries for this, then you need to *correlate* them to the outer query, by specifying that they refer to the same `cc_name` as the outer query:

```
CREATE VIEW test 
AS 
  SELECT cc_name, 
         COUNT()             AS total, 
         (SELECT COUNT() 
          FROM   bed 
          WHERE  cc_name = bed_outer.cc_name
          AND    respatient_id > 0) AS occupied_beds, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM   bed 
          WHERE  cc_name = bed_outer.cc_name
          WHERE  respatient_id IS NULL) AS free_beds 
  FROM   bed AS bed_outer
  GROUP  BY cc_name;
```

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery for information about correlated subqueries.)

But, as OMG Ponies and a1ex07 say, you don't actually need to use subqueries for this if you don't want to.

Comment: +1: I had intended to demonstrate the correlated subquery but forgot.

Comment: thank you for the correct answer, I did need subqueries and this worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Your subqueries return more than 1 row. I think you you need  something like :

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN respatient_id > 0 THEN 1 END) AS occupied_beds,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN respatient_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS free_beds          
 FROM   bed 
 GROUP  BY cc_name
```

You can also try to use `WITH ROLLUP` + pivoting (mostly for learning purposes, it's a much longer query ) :

```
SELECT cc_name, 
MAX(CASE 
 WHEN num_1 = 1 THEN tot_num END) AS free_beds,

MAX(CASE 
 WHEN num_1 = 2 THEN tot_num END) AS occupied_beds,

MAX(CASE 
 WHEN num_1 = IS NULL THEN tot_num END) AS total

FROM
(SELECT cc_name, CASE 
WHEN respatient_id > 0 THEN 1
WHEN respatient_id IS NULL THEN 2
ELSE 3 END as num_1,
COUNT(*) as tot_num
FROM  bed
WHERE 
CASE 
WHEN respatient_id > 0 THEN 1
WHEN respatient_id IS NULL THEN 2
ELSE 3 END != 3
GROUP BY cc_name,
num_1 WITH ROLLUP)A
GROUP BY cc_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT() 
          FROM   bed 
          WHERE  respatient_id > 0 
          GROUP  BY cc_name
```

You need to remove the group-by in the sub query, so possibly something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM   bed 
          WHERE  respatient_id > 0
```

or possibly -- depending on what your application logic is....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from (
          select count(*),cc_name FROM   bed 
          WHERE  respatient_id > 0 
          GROUP  BY cc_name) filterview
```