# I Got this message "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" everytime i enter this query on my database

Tags: sql

These are my tables:
[image]

Every time I enter this query its shows me that my sub query shows more than 1 value my query is

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL)
FROM SALE_RECORD
WHERE INVOICE_ID = (SELECT CP.INVOICE_ID
                    FROM COMPLAINT_AGAINST_PRODUCT CP,
                         COMPLAINT C
                    WHERE C.COMPLAINT_NO = CP.COMPLAINT_NO
                      AND C.STATUS='CLOSED')
```

Comment: first of all run inner query and check what are the number of values it returns, if it returns multiple then you need correct it first.
Run and check this first


SELECT CP.INVOICE_ID
FROM COMPLAINT_AGAINST_PRODUCT CP, COMPLAINT C
WHERE C.COMPLAINT_NO=CP.COMPLAINT_NO AND C.STATUS='CLOSED'

Comment: i checked it and it do give me the desirable answer but it is outer query that is creating problem

Comment: what is the result of your inner query?

Comment: it gives me the invoive id's whose total i want to add

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867271/error-1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

Comment: @ᏒᏗᏂᏬᏝᎴᏬᎶᎶᏗᏝ does inner query return you multiple values?
if it does the use IN instead of '='.

SELECT SUM(TOTAL)
FROM SALE_RECORD
WHERE INVOICE_ID IN (SELECT CP.INVOICE_ID
                    FROM COMPLAINT_AGAINST_PRODUCT CP,
                         COMPLAINT C
                    WHERE C.COMPLAINT_NO = CP.COMPLAINT_NO
                      AND C.STATUS='CLOSED')

Answer (score 1):

Try this. use in operator instead of '='

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL)
FROM SALE_RECORD
WHERE INVOICE_ID IN ( SELECT CP.INVOICE_ID
                      FROM   COMPLAINT_AGAINST_PRODUCT CP, COMPLAINT C
                      WHERE  C.COMPLAINT_NO=CP.COMPLAINT_NO 
                         AND C.STATUS='CLOSED')
```

Answer (score 0):

do this query

```
SELECT INVOICE_ID, COUNT(CP.INVOICE_ID)
FROM COMPLAINT_AGAINST_PRODUCT CP, COMPLAINT C
WHERE C.COMPLAINT_NO=CP.COMPLAINT_NO AND C.STATUS='CLOSED'
GROUP BY INVOICE_ID
ORDER BY count(CP.INVOICE_ID) DESC
```

because there are some INVOICE_ID with 2 or more occurrence.
This is the problem

Comment: i need to add the total i get from invoice_id, not to count them

Comment: total of the cost price of all products replaced. Displaying the total amount will be sufficient.
this is the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL)
FROM SALE_RECORD AS A,
       COMPLAINT_AGAINST_PRODUCT AS B,
       COMPLAINT AS C
WHERE B.COMPLAINT_NO = C.COMPLAINT_NO
AND C.STATUS = ‘CLOSED’
AND B.INVOICE_ID = C.INVOICE_ID
```