# Subquery Issue while fetching the columns from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, db2

I have 3 tables x,y,z

x has username, fullname
y has username, comm, time
z has fusername, musername

I want to select `x.fullname`, `x.username`, `y.comm`, `y.time`

where the inner joined fields are `x.username`, `y.username`, `z.fusername`

My inputs to the `y.username` is where (`z.fusername = 'W'` and all its related entry in the `z.fusername`).

Now,

I tried making a subquery just to extract the fullname for this but got an error code

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
select fullname from x where username in 
(select username from Y where username in
((select musername from tbl_followers where fusername='W'),'W'));
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this data?

Comment: Have a read about joins

Comment: Constrain the number of rows returned by the subquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867271/error-1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

Comment: Thanks for your time , i resolved it. :) The problem was with my sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query and it will work fine. For your query in Oracle you will get **ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row** because in the inner most subquery you are trying to pass both constant as well as dynamic values (what I meant to say is that you can pass either single/multiple constant values or you can use a subquery)

```
SELECT fullname
FROM x
WHERE username IN
  (SELECT username
  FROM Y
  WHERE username IN (
    (SELECT MUSERNAME FROM TBL_FOLLOWERS WHERE FUSERNAME='W') 
  )
  or username='W');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select columns from X as well Y you can use below query -

```
select x.fullname, x.username, y.comm, y.time
  from x, y
 where x.username = y.username
   and (y.username in
       (SELECT MUSERNAME FROM TBL_FOLLOWERS WHERE FUSERNAME = 'W') or
       y.username = 'W')
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using the keyword "in" followed by (in parenthesis and separated by a comma):

- a query which potentially return several results.
- a value.

You cannot do that. Either you put two values or only the query in parenthesis.

So the solution would be to transform your query like this:

```
select fullname from x
 where username 
in 
(
  select username from Y
  where username in 
  (
     select musername from tbl_followers where fusername='W'
   ) 
   or username = 'W'
)
```