# Error #1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE tbl_products
SET Stocks = (Select Stocks 
              WHERE Product_ID IN (3,4,6)) - (SELECT Quantity 
                                              FROM tbl_transactions 
                                              WHERE Product_ID IN (3,4,6) 
                                                AND Date_Time BETWEEN '2020-09-20' AND '2020-09-22');
```

> **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

My problem is, how can I make the "Stocks" accept multiple rows or is it even possible? Is there other solutions besides this? I already run the subquery and it returned 3 rows and I need that 3 rows to be accepted by "Stocks" so it will subtract the values from my first table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867271/error-1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

Comment: Describe the task, not the way which you decide to use for to solve.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

SET stocks can only take one value.  Your subquery is returning more than one.  Make sure it can only return one value.  Run the subquery by itself to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be assing a single value to a `SET` of columns. e.g

```
SET a = 'test', b = 'something'
```

However, if you would like to update multiple rows, you would need `INSERT IGNORE` or to update all the table rows with a specific value then you would just need to write a proper `WHERE` condition.